# How to restrict a regex to only match on non repeating words

Tags: regex

I have the following regex: `((\b\/?counter\b)[^\/]){1}`

I want to match on the word `/counter` which it does, but also matches `/counter/counter` which I don't want it to. I don't want to say much about what comes after `/counter` as long as it's not a forward slash. I just want to ensure that there is only one occurrence of `/counter`

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/7bHqRk/1/
**What should be accepted:**

```
/counter
/counter?
```

**What should not be accepted:**

```
counter
/counter/counter
counter/
```

EDIT:

It was not clear in my question but anything before `/counter` should be accepted as long as it's not counter itself. So http://localhost/controller1/counter is fine while http://localhost/counter/counter is not

Comment: You could use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string `^/counter` https://regex101.com/r/iN4yRe/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Ok thanks that works. But do I need a word boundary here or can I do without one as in your example?

Comment: You could do that if counter should not be part of a longer "word" so that is does not match counters or counter1 or counter_test. It would be `^/counter\b`

Comment: Also, is only 1 occurrence of `counter` allowed in the whole string?

Comment: Try `\B/counter\b(?!/)`, see https://regex101.com/r/5B5usm/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `/counter` at the start of the string, you could use:

```
^/counter\b
```

If `/counter` can not occur afterwards but anything can occur before, you could use a tempered greedy token approach to match anything up until the first occurrence of `/counter` and after that assert that it does not occur anymore using a negative lookahead `(?!`:

```
^(?:(?!/counter\b).)*/counter\b(?!.*/counter\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGeE4g/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works with regards to my question but I just realised that I should have put in my question that it should accept anything before /counter except for /counter itself. So http://localhost/controller1/counter passes but http://localhost/counter/counter fails! Should I use negative lookbehind for this?

Comment: Yes that works exactly like I want it to. At least on regex101. I can't get it to work with C# 's Regex.IsMatch method. Maybe something is different with C# way of parsing. Any idea which character that could confuse it?

Comment: Ok it works perfectly in c# then. There's something else wrong in my code that I will check out. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your pattern to use the start of string token (`^`) and a negative lookahead (`?!`) to ensure `/counter` is not followed by a single backslash (`/`).

```
^\/counter(?!\/)
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/7bHqRk/4)

Matches:

> /counter 
>   /counter?

Does not match:

> counter
>   /counter/counter
>   counter/
>   /counter/
>   /counter/counter/counter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works with regards to my question but I just realised that I should have put in my question that it should accept anything before /counter except for /counter itself. So http://localhost/controller1/counter passes but http://localhost/counter/counter fails! Should I use negative lookbehind for this?

Comment: Just remove the `^` token (denotating the beginning of the string), it will begin matching if `counter` not followed by a `/` is present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

This expression would simply separate them, and we can do what we wish to do after capturing them:

```
.+(counter).\1|(.+)
```

which the first part captures any repeating `counter` or our undesired outputs:

```
.+(counter).\1
```

then the second part would capture what we like to be valid:

```
(.+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TIAawZ/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+(counter).\1|(.+)/gm;
const str = `http://localhost/controller1/counter
http://localhost/counter/counter`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]